# Cannot resolve method 'assertNotThrows' in 'Assertions'

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have this JUnit4 code:

```
Assertions.assertNotThrows(ExceptionNotToThrow.class, () -> {
  .....
});
```

I tried to migrate this code to Junit5 this way:

```
Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(ExceptionNotToThrow.class, () -> {
  .....
});
```

But I get:

```
Cannot resolve method 'assertDoesNotThrow(Class<ExceptionNotToThrow>, <lambda expression>)'
```

Do you know how I can migrate this code properly?

Comment: Check out [the documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html). None of the `assertDoesNotThrows` overloads take an argument specifying the exception type. Do you really need to assert that a _specific_ exception is not thrown, or just that no exception is thrown?

Comment: I need to assert that a specific exception is not thrown.

Comment: May I ask why? That implies other exceptions can be thrown, yet they should not fail the test. Personally, I find that strange.

Comment: This is the code that I received. I haven't implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
try {
    .....
} catch (ExceptionNotToThrow e) {
    Assertions.fail(e)
} catch (Exception e) {
    // this is expected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`Assertions`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) class of JUnit 5 does not have an `assertDoesNotThrow` method overload that accepts the expected exception type. In my opinion, it does not make sense to assert that a *specific* exception is not thrown. Why should a certain exception fail the test, yet the test should pass if any other exception is thrown? If you expect *something* to be thrown, then I would think `assertThrows` is the more appropriate assertion to use.

Regardless, you could do something like the following to mimic the behavior of your JUnit 4 code (though I can't find such an `assertNotThrows` method in [the documentation](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/overview-summary.html) of JUnit 4?).

```java
package sample;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

class Tests {

    @Test
    void test() {
        try {
            // call method that can throw exceptions
        } catch (ExceptionNotToThrow ex) {
            fail("expected exception not to be thrown (see cause)", ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // this is expected; do nothing
        }
    }

    // this is here to allow the code to compile
    static class ExceptionNotToThrow extends RuntimeException {}
}
```

But if you need to do this many times, then I suggest creating your own assertion methods for this. For example:

```java
package sample;

import java.util.function.Supplier;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;

// this API became stable in 5.9
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.assertionFailure;;

public class MyAssertions {

    public static void assertDoesNotThrow(Class<? extends Throwable> type, Executable exec) {
        assertDoesNotThrow(type, exec, (Object) null);
    }

    public static void assertDoesNotThrow(
            Class<? extends Throwable> type, Executable exec, String message) {
        assertDoesNotThrow(type, exec, (Object) message);
    }

    public static void assertDoesNotThrow(
            Class<? extends Throwable> type, Executable exec, Supplier<String> messageSupplier) {
        assertDoesNotThrow(type, exec, (Object) messageSupplier);
    }
    
    private static void assertDoesNotThrow(
            Class<? extends Throwable> type, Executable exec, Object messageOrSupplier) {
        try {
            exec.execute();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (type.isInstance(t)) {
                assertionFailure()
                    .message(messageOrSupplier)
                    .reason("Exception thrown when it should not have been: " + t.getClass().getName())
                    .cause(t)
                    .buildAndThrow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be used like:

```java
package sample;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static sample.MyAssertions.assertDoesNotThrow;

class Tests {

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertDoesNotThrow(ExceptionNotToThrow.class, () -> { /* ... */ });
    }

    // this is here to allow the code to compile
    static class ExceptionNotToThrow extends RuntimeException {}
}
```

Or you could see if a third-party library exists that already provides something like the above.